# Two versions of Hensel's lemma

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field, hensels-lemma

In textbooks on algebraic number theory and $p$-adic numbers, I quite often find two different statements and they are all called Hensel's lemma or at least different versions of Hensel's lemma. The statements I have in mind are as follows:

**Version 1:** Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ and $a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. Assume that
$$|f(a_0)|_p < |f'(a_0)|_p^2.$$
Then there is a unique $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ with $f(a)=0$ and
$$|a-a_0|_p \leq \bigg|\frac{f(a_0)}{f'(a_0)}\biggl|_p.$$

**Version 2:** Let $k$ be the residue field of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and for $f \in \mathbb{Z}_p[X]$, let $\overline{f}$ be the reduction of $f$ to $k$. Consider a monic $f \in \mathbb{Z}_p[X]$. Assume there are two polynomials $g_0,h_0 \in k[X]$ which are coprime over $k$ and with $\overline{f}=g_0h_0$. Then there are two unique polynomials $g,h \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ with $\overline{g}=g_0$, $\overline{h}=h_0$, $(g,h)=\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ and $f=gh$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$.

I am wondering what the logical relation between those two versions is.

**Question:** What is the exact logical relation between version 1 and version 2? Does one implies the other? Are they equivalent?

A related question is here: [Deducing Hensel's lemma for polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122117/deducing-hensels-lemma-for-polynomials). The answer seems to suggest that version 2 might not imply version 1 (although a definite proof is not provided as I understand it).

I found these lecture notes: https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2017fa/LectureNotes9.pdf. On page 7, the author claims that version 2 does imply version 1 but he doesn't give a proof.

Comment: I was thinking about this not too long ago and wasn't able to find a way to deduce Version 1 directly from Version 2. On the other hand I think it's unlikely one could deduce Version 2 directly from Version 1.

Comment: Something you might as well be aware of if you're not already is that Version 2 does imply a weaker version of Version 1. It implies the following "Version 3": if there is an element $\alpha\in k$ such that $\overline f(\alpha)=0$ and $\overline f'(\alpha)\neq0$, then there is a unique $a\in\mathbb Z_p$ with $\overline a=\alpha$ and $f(a)=0$. This comes from taking $g_0(x)=x-\alpha$, where you see the condition $\overline f'(\alpha)\neq0$ equates to the condition $(g_0,h_0)=1$.

Comment: @AlexMathers, thanks for the comment. Yes, I already know "version 3" and that it can be deduced from version 1 as well as from version 2.

Comment: I understand the example in the answer to the first linked question as saying that version 1 does not imply version 2, not the other way around.

Comment: What you need is a generalization of Version $2$ that has Version $1$ as the special case where $g(x) = x - a_0$.  See Theorem 4.1 in “An Introduction to $G$-Functions” by Dwork, Gerotto, and Sullivan, where $f’(a_0)$ in Version $1$ is replaced by the resultant of $g$ and $h$ in the generalization of Version $2$. That resultant becomes $f’(a_0)$ when $g(x)=x-a_0$.

Comment: While it is good to see how different results called Hensel’s Lemma can be seen as special cases of some common theorem, you also should accept that the label “Hensel’s Lemma” is also a generic name for any kind of $p$-adic result turning an approximate calculation into an exact calculation (of a root, a factorization, and so on). So do not expect that all possible things called Hensel’s Lemma must have a common generalization. Unlike what page $7$ in your MIT link says, different things called Hensel’s Lemma are *not* “all equivalent by definition”.

Comment: But in the specific cases of Version $1$ and what Alex calls Version $3$, they really are equivalent. The nonobvious implication from Version $3$ to Version $1$ is Theorem $5.4$ in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/hensel.pdf.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, the answer to the linked question presents an example where version 2 can be applied but not version 1.

Comment: But @russoo, say version 1 is of the form "If A, then B" and version 2 says "if C, then D". What Lubin's linked example shows is that C can be the case while A is not the case. This makes it unlikely that we can prove version 2 from version 1; because to prove version 2, we have to start by assuming that C *is the case*. But now to even invoke version 1 in a proof we would need to assume A somewhere; the example shows that (unless there's some smart trick around it) we cannot.

Comment: Whereas it seems as if @AlexMathers' comment and KCd's third comment together say that version 2 indeed does imply version 1. I would think of version 1 as a special case, something which presupposes more restrictive conditions than versions 2 or 3.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, yes the comments of KCd (and his reference) and AlexMathers show that version 2 implies version 1.